# AWS project structure using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am working on a Python and AWS course on coursera. However instead of creating s3 , api gateway and others using boto3 I am using terraform. Till now everything is going fine however I am facing a issue.Below is my lambda directory structure

[image]

[image]

Every lambda has a different directory structure and I have to cd in each directory to apply changes using terraform apply.

Example

Below is my lambda code in terraform for one of the lambda function.<<validate.tf>>

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-2"
}

terraform {
  required_version = "> 0.14"
  required_providers {
    aws = "~> 3.0"
  }
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "nyeisterraformstatedata2"
    key = "api_gateway/lambda_function/terraform_api_gateway_lambda_validate.tfstate"
    region = "us-east-2"

    dynamodb_table = "terraform-up-and-running-locks-2"
    encrypt = true
  }
}

data "archive_file" "zip_file" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "${path.module}/lambda_dependency_and_function"
  output_path = "${path.module}/lambda_dependency_and_function.zip"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "get_average_rating_lambda" {
  filename      = "lambda_dependency_and_function.zip"
  function_name = "validate"
  role          = data.aws_iam_role.lambda_role_name.arn
  handler       = "validate.lambda_handler"

  # The filebase64sha256() function is available in Terraform 0.11.12 and later
  # For Terraform 0.11.11 and earlier, use the base64sha256() function and the file() function:
  # source_code_hash = "${base64sha256(file("lambda_function_payload.zip"))}"
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256(data.archive_file.zip_file.output_path)

  runtime = "python3.8"

  depends_on = [data.archive_file.zip_file]
}
```

<<variable.tf>>

```
data "aws_iam_role" "lambda_role_name" {
  name = "common_lambda_role_s3_api_gateway_2"
}
```

Based on the comment below I created a main.tf with following code

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-2"
}


module "test" {
  source = "../validate"

}
```

but I am trying to import using import statement its giving me an error and I am not able to figure out how to solve it

> > `terraform import module.test.aws_lambda_function.test1 get_average_rating_lambda`

```
Warning: Backend configuration ignored
│ 
│   on ../validate/validate.tf line 10, in terraform:
│   10:   backend "s3" {
│ 
│ Any selected backend applies to the entire configuration, so Terraform expects provider configurations only in the root module.
│ 
│ This is a warning rather than an error because it's sometimes convenient to temporarily call a root module as a child module for testing purposes, but this backend configuration block will have no
│ effect.
╵

Error: resource address "module.test.aws_lambda_function.test1" does not exist in the configuration.

Before importing this resource, please create its configuration in module.test. For example:

resource "aws_lambda_function" "test1" {
  # (resource arguments)
}
```

So my question is there a way for terraform to tell which all files have change and apply them in one go rather than one by one.Since I am new to terraform too so if anyone think that this is the wrong way to structing the project please do let me know.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is create a new directory with a main.tf file and make it a project that contains your whole cloud environment. Each of these existing folders could be imported as a module. If each of your folders is a running terraform project, it can already be imported as a module without changing it.

You would then use the `terraform import` command to import each of the resources, in a fashion similar to `terraform import module.aws_lambda_function my_lambda_id` for each lambda and any other managed resources.

Then, instead of a state file for each lambda, you would have a state file for your whole environment. From there, terraform is smart enough to detect the individual changes and update accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the response.let me give it a try.

Comment: "If each of your folders is a running terraform project, it can already be imported as a module without changing it."  Can you elaborate a bit.Each of the subfolder under lambda folder is independent of each other and has its own state file if this is what you mean by running terraform project.I created below config file in main.tf .Now when I do terraform plan ...its creating a new lambda function.Shouldn't it point to the existing one.
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-2"
}


module "test" {
  source = "../validate"
}

Comment: A valid terraform project can be imported as a module and run If you change the project that you run from, you start again with a new state file. You can update the state file to include the existing items by using `terraform import`. For the code you have there, you will import to `module.test.aws_lambda_function.<name in your module>` See if you can do it with one of your folders, and then build out.

Comment: I edited my post to include my code and error I am getting while importing

Comment: You will need to move your backend configuration up to the root of the terraform project. Also, it looks like your resource address needs to be updated. The resource address should point to the actual lambda resource in your module - you can find it from your module code.